# Where do I find my Windows 7 registration key if I lose the DVD?

Tags: windows-7, product-key

I lost my Windows installation DVD. I don't remember the registration key for my Windows installation, and I want to get rid of the pop-ups stating that my Windows is not genuine.

I learned that the registration key is provided with the program, but where is it?

Comment: If you've already entered the product key and activated Windows, you should no longer be getting the popup warnings. If you haven't already entered the product key, you cannot extract it from the registry, because it's not there to extract. Better start looking for that DVD, I think.

Comment: buy one dude :)

Comment: Do you not have an OEM sticker with the key on the computer's case?

Answer (score 2):

This will find the key already entered in your system
http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/
and is free

Comment: There's a similar piece of software called [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) that is standalone (does not require installation).

Comment: It might be free but it comes with a cost. It silently installs the malware Smileyswelove in every browser on your system.

Comment: keyfinder does that or Produkey? I did not see that in the scans I have done for keyfinder.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is custom-built and you have a retail version of Windows installed, there is no way to legally activate it unless you have the retail product key.

If your computer is an OEM machine (from Dell or HP, for instance), the OEM product key will be on a sticker affixed to the computer's case. The installed version of Windows must match the version that is written on the sticker. The product key will not work with any other version.

As [Aaron commented](https://superuser.com/questions/639182/where-do-i-find-my-windows-7-registration-key-if-i-lose-the-dvd#comment799304_639182), if you are being told by Windows that it is not genuine, then the key is not installed and it is not "locatable" anywhere on the computer.

- If you can locate the box that the software came in, the product key
  will be written on a sticker inside.
- If you happen to still have the receipt for the retail copy of
  Windows, you **may** have luck if you call Microsoft and request a
  new key, but this is unlikely if you bought it anywhere but from MS
  directly.
- Your only other option is to buy another copy. I've purchased legal retail Microsoft software at [DiscountMountainSoftware.com](http://www.discountmountainsoftware.com).

---

Your friendly neighborhood Spiderman wishes to remind you not to pirate software.

Comment: Totally agree with this statement. There are conceivable situations where a dvd sticker is damaged, and retrieving the key used to originally install a valid copy of the software is where I think retrieving the stored key is legitimate

Comment: This is true. I use Produkey and MagicKeyfinder all the time as I always loose track of them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the key is under the laptop battery if you're using a laptop. This is of course assuming that Windows came pre-installed and you just happen to have an install disc on hand. Got a bit mixed up myself over that once. I haven't seen it myself but if they'd stick it under the battery they might put it inside the case as well. Otherwise the key may be printed in a more noticeable place on the computer, or not at all.

If, as seems likely, you manually installed Windows on a machine not already loaded with it (perhaps you bought a used machine, built one or upgraded Windows) and never entered the key in the first place then you are probably out of luck - you'll have to do as Moses said and get a new key.